# KDM Login Will Not Accept Username & Password

Tags: kde, login-screen, kdm

I have just installed KDE , set up my preferred environment (with desktop cube effects color scheme, set the splash screen to "minimalist" and also installed ksnapshot.) Installation was done with the terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install kde-desktop
```

Everything seemed to be working fine (actually pretty stellar.) Then I did a reboot to make sure all my changes could settle-in properly. When I got back to the login screen, which is the KDM login screen I selected in the setup process, however, there seems to be no user account for me (or anyone else for that matter.) If I click "switch user," my only option is something that says, "Unused (:0, vt8)" which is already selected. If I type in my previous username and password, it won't recognize it and acts as though I've typed in error.

While I cannot login, I do seem to have other options. The blue down-arrow gives me options of which desktop to use. 
    options are

- "Defualt,"
- "KDE Plasma Workspace,"
- "KDE Plasma Workspace (failsafe session),"
- "Ubuntu," and
- "Failsafe."

The red "shutdown" button on the screen gives me the options,

- "Switch User,"
- "Restart X Server,"
- "remote Login,"
- "Console Login," and
- "Shutdown."

Would someone please help me get it functioning again?It seems this has happened before.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2003566&highlight=kdm+username+password

This person closed their thread before there were any responses, so I wasn't able to post that I'm having the same issue. The "long-story short" version of this is, KDM won't accept (or seem to recognize the existence of) my username or password, or any other, and I cannot switch to another login manager to try that because that would require that it accept my credentials first. If it helps to know, before my reboot and subsequently getting stuck at KDM, LightDM logged me into KDE just fine.

Comment: Are you sure you're using your *username*, and not your *full name*? LightDM displays you with the fullname, while KDM requires you to log in using a plain username. What is the username you entered? And can you log in on a VT? (Ctrl+Alt+F1)

Comment: Yes, I am using my username and not my full name. I actually have not had the experience that LightDM asks for your full name. I've been typing in my username in LDM the whole time I've been using it. No, I cannot log in with Ctrl+Alt+f1. Trying to do so returns "login incorrect." I also cannot boot in recovery mode with the shift key or boot from a LiveCD. Why are you asking me for my username?

Comment: I didn't say that LightDM was *asking* for your full name. Read again. :) And this wouldn't be the first question for someone not to remember his *username*. Based on the full name the Ubuntu installer generates a username which people don't remember afterwards or they use wrong casing, that's why I wanted to know what you were trying exactly. As your question stands now it's just a plain password recovery question...

Comment: "As your question stands now it's just a plain password recovery question" 

Even where the only user it seems to recognize is that "Unused (:0, vt8)" thing? I have tried my username (Valkyr) and also "Val" as "val," "Val," "Valkyr" and "valkyr." And I'm using the same password I've always used to log in when I could still access LightDM. How would I go about finding the username that Ubuntu Installer generated if what you mentioned about the installer-generated password were the problem?

Comment: *installer-generated username - sorry.

Comment: The installer generates lower-case-only usernames. So your username is probably **not** "Valkyr". Just boot with a Live CD, mount the hard drive and inspect the `/etc/passwd` file (or post it here).

Comment: @gertvdijk Explaining how this is just a password recovery question has taken quite a few words, suggesting that there is an important sense in which it's not quite just [the same as that](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password). I'd recommend posting an answer here explaining that. It seems to me that could help others.